# Accessing SQLite3 database from webpage

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm looking to pull names from an SQLite3 database and make changes on a webpage with my Python code.

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem. If you need help with how try giving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read.

Comment: @PratikThakare I apologize, I have a database that includes employee names and numerical identifiers, I'm looking to read the names from the database, and produce buttons using HTML with the names from the database. I would also like to make changes to the database with a "Edit employees" button. such as editing the numerical identifiers or deleting them from the database

Comment: Is there any framework or library you are using or simply vanilla python, js, html, and python's standard sqlite3 library?

Comment: @PratikThakare I'm using flask, but recently been considering switching to django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it simple, you have two ways you can achieve this

## Server-side Rendering

You can make use of [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) template engine to build the HTML after populating the required values from the database.
You should be able to understand how to use jinja by following flask's own documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/templating/).

## Client-side Rendering

You can serve the HTML, Javascript, and CSS file normally and then make API calls to endpoints implemented on the Flask back end, which will return data in JSON format.

Once you have the data, you can utilize javascript to change the values or create elements directly. (Like create the buttons once you have all the names by using the data and DOM methods)

You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make API calls and if you are confused you can install something like [postman](https://www.postman.com/) use its GUI to test your APIs and then generate code from postman.